# MySQL is updating twice as many rows as intended

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Stuck here...

I select several hundred rows and I reference them for other stuff not related to my question. Once I'm done with them, *I simply want to go back and update those same rows with a "Completed" value.*. When I select the post_ids and update them through my php file, **the number of rows updated are always twice as many as I intended** For example, if my limit is 2 rows, it updates 4 rows, if my limit is 500 rows it updates 1000 rows, etc.

Intended to get five rows updated in the image below:
[Intended to get five rows updated in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3vS0.png)
This is the error, it updates 10 rows instead of five
[This is the error, it updates 10 rows instead of five](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFSe8.png)

```
<?php

  DEFINE('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
  DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
  DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
  DEFINE('DB_DATABASE', 'crontest');

  $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

  if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error ('.mysqli_connect_errno().') '.mysqli_connect_error());
  }

    // grab desired list of entries

    $acfaddress = "SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM gmoney_postmeta WHERE conversion_completed='Not Completed' ORDER BY post_id ASC LIMIT 5";
    $acfresult = $conn->query($acfaddress);

    $address_id = array();
    while($addressrow = $acfresult->fetch_assoc()) {
      $address_id[] = $addressrow["post_id"];
      // other code here for my geocode csv stuff but not related to my question...
    }


  // problem begins here
  $fromselect = join(',', array_map('intval', $address_id)); 
  var_dump($fromselect); // becomes "61,65,69,73,77"

  // set to 'Completed' on specific post_ids 

  $acfcompleted="UPDATE gmoney_postmeta SET conversion_completed='Completed' WHERE post_id IN (".$fromselect.")";

  $conn->query($acfcompleted);

  $conn->close(); 

?>
```

I tried it as "61","65","69","73","77" and still the problem persists. If I hand type a string that looks exactly the same it works fine

```
$fromstring="61,65,69,73,77"; // this works, but then why not $fromselect from up above...
$acfcompleted="UPDATE gmoney_postmeta SET conversion_completed='Completed' WHERE post_id IN (".$fromstring.")"
```

I have also tried this but the problem persists

```
$acfcompleted= "UPDATE gmoney_postmeta JOIN (SELECT post_id from gmoney_postmeta where conversion_completed = 'Not Completed' 
                    ORDER BY post_id ASC LIMIT 5) t1 USING (post_id)
SET conversion_completed='Completed'" ;
```

Also when I run these commands in phpmyadmin, everything works fine. **Its only when I try to update post_ids referenced from the SELECT code in the php file**

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Why would you configure this script to act as a 404 handler?

Comment: @YourCommonSense ty for the similar answer link, the second request was the favicon. All Fixed